# Are there satirical news sites in Chinese, like The Onion?

Tags: resources, reading

Sometimes I like to have a laugh and read satirical news sites, like [The Onion](https://www.theonion.com/), e.g.

> [Experts Concerned Pale Russian Mystic Constantly At Trump’s Side May Attempt To Influence 2020 Election](https://politics.theonion.com/experts-concerned-pale-russian-mystic-constantly-at-tru-1841836220)

It'd probably be beneficial for me to read in Chinese, but I can't find an equivalent.

**Question**: Are there satirical news sites in Chinese, like The Onion?

Maybe they don't exist, as it's not really a typical Chinese behavior to "take the piss".  The relevant Baidu search is [`讽刺新闻`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E8%AE%BD%E5%88%BA%E6%96%B0%E9%97%BB) but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of news is called “洋葱新闻” in Chinese. I don't think there is such kind of news sites, but you can find some account named by it on weibo.

Comment: 洋葱新闻 公众号确实很不错( ﾟ∀ ﾟ)

Answer (score 2):

In Hong Kong, there is a pro-democracy newspaper called Apple Daily/蘋果日報, which writes satirical reports against the Chinese Communist Party and its regime. It often complements them with Cantonese videos called 動新聞, which are comedic and mock the event in question.

Apart from this niche, though, 蘋果日報 does produce mainstream reports and frequent tabloid news as well. Just take note that the texts are better read in Cantonese.